# Continue sending packets after send FIN

Tags: tcp

My wireshark had captured following packets:

```
2009    773 src dst TCP 1514    [TCP Retransmission] 51940 > http [ACK] Seq=11680 Ack=559 Win=3847 Len=1448
2010    775 src dst TCP 1514    [TCP Retransmission] 51940 > http [ACK]  Seq=11680 Ack=559 Win=3847 Len=1448
2011    779 src dst TCP 1514    [TCP Retransmission] 51940 > http [ACK] Seq=11680 Ack=559 Win=3847 Len=1448
2012    781 src dst TCP 66  51940 > http [FIN, ACK] Seq=15579 Ack=559 Win=3847 Len=0 <====FIN
2013    786 src dst TCP 1514    [TCP Retransmission] 51940 > http [ACK] Seq=11680 Ack=559 Win=3847 Len=1448 
2014    802 src dst TCP 1514    [TCP Retransmission] 51940 > http [ACK] Seq=11680 Ack=559 Win=3847 Len=1448 
2029    833 src dst TCP 1514    [TCP Retransmission] 51940 > http [ACK] Seq=11680 Ack=559 Win=3847 Len=1448
```

So I have some questions, when app sends a FIN, does the TCP connection state turn to fin_wait_1? Then why it is still sending packets?

Or do I misunderstand fin_wait_1?

Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the trace, except for the FIN packed, the others are all TCP Retransmitions. But as the trace is incomplete, it's not clear as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interesting question. First of all, you are correct that when an application calls close() on a socket, a FIN is sent and the socket enters the FIN-WAIT-1 state. No further send calls will be accepted by the socket in this state however packets which were send **before** the FIN and have yet to be acknowledged, will continue to be retransmitted. This appears to be what is happening in your case.

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.5

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I don't know why FIN was not resent.

Comment: I don't see any timestamps on your post - perhaps RTO hasn't expired for the FIN?